# Ruby short Socket.gethostname in RHEL6

Tags: ruby, hostname, rhel6

in RHEL5, the default Ruby's `Socket::gethostname` returns short hostname without domain name. In RHEL6 it returns the hostname *including* the domain name.

This is caused by different system `hostname` functionality in RHEL6 which can be fixed in SH scripts using `hostname -s`. Is there any `Socket::gethostname` parameter to fix it in Ruby?

It is possible to fix by parsing the output using regular expression or using system call, e.g. `'hostname -s'.strip`, but neither is an easy nor a nice solution.

Could you help?

Thanks
Jan

Answer (score 0):

As you might see in the [rubydoc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-c-gethostname)+click-to-toggle-source, `gethostname` is a simple wrapper to `c stdlib`.

That said, you might try to compile and execute the below code. As soon as it returns not what you want, you are probably stuck to `hostname -s`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int, char **) {
  char buf[1025];
  gethostname(buf, 1024);

  printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for details. I am rather new to Ruby (updating others code) and have not found the source codes yet.
The solution is not from the fastest, but as it is not executed thousands of times, it shall not mind. It is just not methodical.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to return everything up to the first '.'

```
require 'socket'
hostname = Socket.gethostname[/^[^.]+/]
```